# Can I automatically create sub domains on a specific domain for all VirtualHosts?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

If I have the following Apache configuration and wildcard *. s1.ex.com pointing to the server

```
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
ServerName example.net
DocumentRoot /home/user2/web/example.net
</VirtualHost>
```

Is it possible to automatically get the domains `example.com.s1.ex.com` `example.net.s1.ex.com` to automatically point to their respective vhost?

Edit: I'm looking for a solution that automatically do the same as if I had added ServerAlias as manually.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a ServerAlias:

```
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias example.com.s1.ex.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
ServerName example.net
ServerAlias example.net.s1.ex.com
DocumentRoot /home/user2/web/example.net
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Also note that wildcard characters (* and ?) are allowed in the argument(s) to ServerAlias, so you could even do "ServerAlias example.com.*" and "ServerAlias example.net.*".

Comment: I know of ServerAlias. I'm looking for a solution that automatically do the same as if I had added ServerAlias manually.

Comment: Got it.  If you have a large number of domains and want it to happen automatically, I'm sure that you can do it with mod_rewrite.  Unfortunately, I am not a mod_rewrite expert.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for for mass virtual hosting?

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/mass.html

http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-mass-virtualhosting-with-apache2-mod_rewrite-mod_userdir-mod_suexec-on-centos-5.3

Comment: Maybe.
I'm looking for a solution that will automatically add ServerAlias for all VirtualHost in a specific domain (eg. s1.ex.com) and so the DocumentRoot to be anything for the VirtualHost. 
In practice, it is a temporary domain name while waiting for DNS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [mod_vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html#examples).

```
LoadModule vhost_alias_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
<VirtualHost *>
  VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%-5.0.%-4
</VirtualHost>
```

*example.com.s1.ex.com* is now served from `/var/www/example.com`.